# Consulta SQL a queryset de DJango

Tags: sql, django, django-models

tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.id) e.id, e.nombre, e.apellido, e.estado, e.documento, c.nivelado, s.nombre AS semestre, t.nombre AS tipo 
            FROM estudiante e 
                JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id 
                JOIN semestre s ON s.id=c.semestre_id 
                JOIN tipo t ON t.id=c.tipo_id 
                ORDER BY e.id, s.orden DESC
```

Quiero hacerla con Queryset de djanango algo así `estudiantes = Estudiante.objects.all()` pero no se como hacer los join y el order by.

Este es mi modelo de base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo los modelos implicados en la consulta

**Estudiante**

```
ESTADOS = (
    (0, 'Activo'),
    (1, 'Inactivo'),
    (2, 'Egresado'),
    (3, 'Graduado'),
)
TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS = (
    (0, 'Tarjeta de indentidad'),
    (1, 'Cédula'),
    (2, 'Pasaporte'),
    (3, 'Cédula extrangera'),
)

class Genero(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre", max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'genero'


class Estudiante(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombres", max_length=200)
    apellido = models.CharField(verbose_name="Apellidos", max_length=200)
    tipo_documento = models.IntegerField(choices=TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS, default=1)
    documento = models.CharField(verbose_name="Número de documento", max_length=200, unique=True)
    celular = models.CharField(verbose_name="Celular", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(verbose_name="Telefono", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, verbose_name="Género", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha de nacimiento")
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Correo electronico", null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(verbose_name="Dirección", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADOS, default=0)
    semestre_inicio = models.ForeignKey(Semestre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")

    def __str__(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.nombre, self.apellido))

    def get_tipo_documento(self):
        tipo = TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS[self.tipo_documento][1]
        return tipo

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'estudiante'
```

**Semestre**

```
class Semestre(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre", max_length=200, unique=True)
    orden =  models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['orden']
        db_table = 'semestre'
```

**Caracterizacion**

```
class Tipo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre", max_length = 200)
    default = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tipo de caracterización"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tipo de caracterizaciones"
        ordering = ['nombre']
        db_table = 'tipo'


class Caracterizacion(models.Model):
    SI_NO = (
        (1,'Sí'),
        (2,'No'),
    )
    estudiante = models.ForeignKey(Estudiante, verbose_name="Estudiante", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    descripcion = models.TextField(verbose_name="Descripción", null=True, blank=True)
    semestre = models.ForeignKey(Semestre, verbose_name="Semestre", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, verbose_name="Tipo", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nivelado = models.IntegerField(choices = SI_NO, default=1)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Usuario", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")

    def __str__(self):
        return ('{} - {}'.format(self.estudiante, self.semestre))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Caracterización"
        verbose_name_plural = "Caracterizaciones"
        ordering = ['created']
        db_table = 'caracterizacion'
```

Comment: Pregunta duplicada, diría yo. Aquí tienes una propuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/215604/55334

Answer (score 0):

los `joins` se hacen simplemente igualando

```
caracterizaciones = Caracterizacion.objects.filter(....) # los puntos suspensivos los para indicar que apliques los filtros que necesites
semestres = Semestre.objects.filter(...)
tipo = Tipo.objects.get(id=param_id) # param_id es una variable que me invento  e imagino que tiene un valor que recibo como parametro
# sabiendo que `.filter()` devuelve una lista y `.get()` un objeto
estudiantes = Estudiante.objectst.filter(
    caracterizacion__in=caracterizaciones, # a este atributo le añado `__in` porque estoy igualando con una lista
    semestre__in=semestres,
    tipo=tipo # aqui solo igualo porque `tipo` es un único objecto
)
```

te he hecho con `filter` y con `get` para hacerte el ejemplo con los dos casos pero tu puedes hacerlo como necesites.

Cabe resaltar que puedo aplicar el  filtro `caracterizacion` desde el modelo `Estudiante` aunque este no tenga este atributo porque el modelo `Caracterizacion` tiene un atributo FK de `Estudiante` Django con su magia crea un enlace interno para hacernos la vida mas fácil.

Para conocer un poco más como trabajar las consultas con Django revisa [este](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) enlace.

Comment: Cuando escribes característica te refieres a caracterizaciones?

Comment: Si perdona, con las prisas escribí mal. He editado mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya ha pasado tiempo después de la publicación de la pregunta, me permito adjuntar una posible solución por si alguien más la llegase a necesitar.

En vista que ya tienes diseñada la consulta en lenguaje SQL te seria fácil hacer uso del siguiente método que proporciona Django llamado "raw" en donde podrás mandarle como parámetro un String con la consulta SQL

**Ejemplo:**

```
Model.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM tabla')
```

Para ver más documentación sobre consultas SQL desde Django podrías revisar el siguiente enlace de la documentación oficial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/